Mean aspect of polygons based on DTM file in ArcGIS Pro
I need to calculate the mean aspect of a number of polygons in a shapefile.
I have a DTM (guess it's a raster?) file that I already used to calculate the aspect of 20x20 pixels in my area of interest, simply using the Aspect tool in Spatial Analyst Tools. Now I am a bit stuck, because I couldn't find any hints on forums, or maybe I am unable to understand the solution proposed.
I tried fiddling with statistics table, guessing this might be a solution to my problem, to no avail.
Any suggestions?

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-spatial-analyst-questions/calculate-mean-aspect-for-polygons/m-p/67951
